# Matlab: cell array or several multidimensional matrices (iterating)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, cell

I have to create 50-100 multidimensional matrices (on of these matrices contains about 7 matrices with dimension 25*10). I want to store them, so that I can iterate through them and manipulate their entries. Since I've read that it's not a good idea to concatenate the name of the matrices with a number and eval(), I thought I could store all of them in one cell array. But then I read that cell arrays shoudn't be used if the matrices contain only numbers and no strings, because they're to slow to process in comparison with matrices.
Now I hope you can advise me how to approach to an decision.

Answer (score 1):

If all your matrices are of the same size, it's best to use a 4D matrix, with size 25x10x7x100. You say "about 7": is that number the same for all the 3D matrices? If not, I think a cell array is the right approach.

Cell arrays are needed when the matrices you want to store are not all of the same size, and so cannot be stored (at least no easily) in a higher-dimensional matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unclear, but here's an attempt to address your quandery:

Cell arrays allow you to store "mixed" data - string in one, matrix in another, etc. Since you are talking about different matrices (size, number) in different "cells", a cell array is a perfectly reasonable way to store them. But if the matrices were all the same size, then you would be better off storing them in a single matrix (with an additional dimension). In reality the overhead of inefficiency is small when the matrix itself is large - the time it takes to "call up" one matrix is small compared to the time to access all 250 elements, etc.